# passing data from one view controller to other showing nil

Tags: swift, swift4

//first `viewController` where `Tvshowpath` contains data. I print `Tvshowpath2` in this `viewController` data is printed//

```
@objc var TvshowPath = NSDictionary() 
override func viewDidLoad()
 {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  let playerPage = 
  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
  "playerLayer")
   as! PlayerLayerViewController
   playerPage.TvshowPath2 = TvshowPath
   print(playerPage.TvshowPath2)
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playerPage, animated: true)

}
```

//In the second `viewController` where `Tvshowpath2` data getting nil

```
@objc var TvshowPath2 = NSDictionary()

override func viewDidLoad()
 {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   print(TvshowPath2)
}
```

Comment: is second vc presented on top of a navigation?

Comment: yes ,playerLayerviewcontroller is second vc

Comment: As you described, you are opening new controller on viewdidload only... and TvshowPath is not been set before passing it.

Comment: Not related, but: any reason why use `NSDictionary` in Swift 4? Prefers Swift version when available to NSStuff. Also, please name your var starting with a lowercase. Don't you have any logs in console because we tend to not push in `viewDidLoad()` directly because it's not because the ViewController has loaded that it is in view window and can push.

Comment: what changes i have to made in the code to get data in other view controller